# Como fazer uma busca em coluna varchar com carácter de contra barra

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Eu estou tentando realizar uma query em uma tabela parecida com a abaixo através de um campo `diretorio`.

```
+----------+---------------+----------------------------------------+
|id_imagem |  data_upload  |               diretorio                |
+----------+---------------+----------------------------------------+
|   1      | 2019-05-18    |   \\xxx.xxx.xxx.xx\xyzdnas\img1.png    |
|   2      | 2019-05-18    |   \\xxx.xxx.xxx.xx\dasdadg\img2.png    |
|   3      | 2019-05-18    |   \\xxx.xxx.xxx.xx\gnwwefi\img3.png    |
|   4      | 2019-05-18    |   \\xxx.xxx.xxx.xx\gdfgthh\img4.png    |
|   5      | 2019-05-18    |   \\xxx.xxx.xxx.xx\njfsdfu\img5.png    |
+----------+---------------+----------------------------------------+
```

A coluna que eu uso para condição é a `diretorio`, porém, eu tenho somente o endereço de IP e a pasta em que os arquivos estão, e eu preciso obter todas as imagens que estão naquela pasta pelo BD.

Eu inicialmente estava tentando a busca:

```
SELECT * FROM db.tb WHERE diretorio LIKE '%\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xx\njfsdfu%';
```

Porém, a busca não retorna os valores corretamente, fiz algumas pesquisas no Google e encontrei buscas como essas abaixo porém também não obtive sucesso:

```
SELECT * FROM db.tb WHERE diretorio LIKE '%\%\%xxx.xxx.xxx.xx\%njfsdfu%' ESCAPE '|';

SELECT * FROM db.tb WHERE diretorio LIKE '%\\\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xx\\njfsdfu%' ESCAPE '|';
```

porém não consegui obter um resultado.

Alguém sabe como fazer essa busca?

PS: Estou utilizando o `MySQL` e o campo da coluna `diretorio` é `VARCHAR(600)`

Comment: Como o caractere \ é um caractere de escape então é só duplicar (\\) para representar uma única \.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma possibilidade é utilizar a função `LOCATE` do MYSQL, A função retorna a posição da primeira ocorrência de uma substring em uma string. Se a substring não for encontrada, essa função retornará 0.

```
SELECT * FROM db.tb where locate("\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xx\\njfsdfu\\", diretorio) > 0;
```

ou então utilize o like escapando as barras inversas.

```
SELECT * FROM tb WHERE diretorio LIKE '%\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xx\\njfsdfu%' ESCAPE '|';
```

[MySQL LIKE vs LOCATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499438/mysql-like-vs-locate)

Comment: Com o locate aqui funcionou perfeitamente, porém com o LIKE não obtive sucesso. Obrigado!